# Why the measurement is "fishy" in this Mininet network emulation?

Tags: networking, network-programming, mininet

I have a mininet configuration, which looks like this:

```
    host1               host3 
      |                  |
      |                  |
   switch1 ---------- switch2
      |                  |
      |                  |
    host2               host4
```

The link speed in every connection is 10Mbps.

First when I run **iperf between h1 and h3**, and in the same time (in parallel) I run iperf between **h2 and h4**, the transfer rate is the **same** for both cases. (~6 Mbps)

But, when I run, **host1 iperf host4** and **host3 iperf host2**, the transfer rate for **h1-h4** is nearly **double** compared to **h3-h2**. (~10 Mbps)

Can someone explain to me why this is so, because the **length** of the route is the **same**, the **link speed** is the **same**, **everything** is the **same** ? 
Why in the first case there is an interference and in the second isnt?